# cakephp linked model not showing in hasmany

Tags: cakephp, model, model-associations

I have three Models in cakephp

```
//Union
  public $hasMany = 'Member';
```

and

```
//Member
 public $hasOne = 'Post';
```

where as post contains post names

Now the problem is when I use:

```
$this->Union->findById(1);
```

in Union controller it shows linked Members but not name of posts

```
[Union] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [Name] => Dawa vyapar mandal
            [created] => 2014-03-31 14:08:12
        )

    [Member] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [Name] => Ashish
                    [post_id] => 1
                    [union_id] => 1
                    [created] => 2014-03-31 14:11:02
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [Name] => Ashu
                    [post_id] => 1
                    [union_id] => 1
                    [created] => 2014-07-01 15:01:15
                )
        )
)
```

so how to achieve Post Model inside Member Model?

Comment: Use like this:    $this->Union->recursive=2;$this->Union->findById(1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the model to be recursive to the level upto which you need data.

In your case, you need the data upto 2nd level, so make recursive as -

```
$this->Union->recursive = 2;
```

And after that find your data -

```
$this->Union->findById(1)
```